# Dividir texto em partes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Preciso pegar um pedaço específico de um aquivo .txt que esteja entre `<tag>` e `</tag>`.
Porém preciso pegar todas as linhas onde isso acontece.

Exemplo:

```
<tag1>titulo</tag1>
<tag2>subtitulo</tag2> 

texto... 

<tag2>subtitulo</tag2> 
texto... 

<tag1>titulo</tag1> 
<tag2>subtitulo</tag2> 
texto...
```

Eu quero pegar o texto entre essas tags e salvar.

Comment: Você quer pegar o texto entre as tags <tag1> e <tag2>, é isso? Se não for problema colocar o código da aplicação, ficaria mais fácil ajudar...

Comment: Isso!
Meu sistema precisa fazer isso com esse txt.

Comment: Não percebi se queres capturar o `titulo` e `subtitulo` ou o que está fora das tags como `texto...`.

Comment: e por que a `<tag2>` não está fechada?

Comment: Quero pegar o que está fora das tags.

Comment: esqueci de fechar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente esse código:

```
var pattern = /<tag.*?>(.*?)<\/tag.*?>/g; //Padrão que a regex vai dar Match
var reader = new FileReader(); //Leitor do arquivo txt
var output = ""; //Variável de texto onde será carregado o conteúdo do txt
reader.onload = function (e) {  //Função para leitura após o carregamento do reader
            output = e.target.result;
            displayContents(output);
        }; //Fim da função
        reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]); //insira o path para seu txt
var m;

do {
    m = pattern.exec(output); //executa o padrão da regex e armazena os val em m
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]); //mostra o resultado no console do browser
    }
} while (m);
```

Explicação do código:

- A função a seguir carrega o arquivo txt através de um `FileReader`
- Passa seu conteúdo para a variável `output`.
- Imprime o conteúdo que deu match na regex no console do browser.

Explicação da regex:

```
/<tag.*?>(.*?)<\/tag.*?>/g;
```

- `<tag` Encontra a sequencia exatamente igual a `<tag`
- `.*?>` Prossegue (sem capturar) por todos os caracteres até a primeira ocorrência do `>`.
- `(.*?)<\/tag` Captura todo o conteúdo no grupo de captura 1 até a primeira ocorrência de `</tag`
- `.*?>` Prossegue (sem capturar) por todos os caracteres até a primeira ocorrência do `>`.
- `/g` É um modificador da regex, indica que deve continuar tentando dar match até o fim da sequencia de texto.